# `adb` cannot detect Oppo F5

Tags: android, adb, android-sdk-tools, usb-debugging, platform-tools

Today I wanted to learn Flutter. So, I read through the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows) and found out that I can run my app on my real device (Oppo f5 in this case).

I do have enabled USB Debugging. And the MTP works fine (I can transfer files with the speed of light).

When I enable USB Debugging, a driver install window pops up (I'm using Windows 7 x64). It tries to detect **ADB Interface** from Windows Update and fails; then tries to install from the *preconfigured driver folders,* then fails.

Please do not tell me that I must use an emulator. I have a mere 3GB of RAM that can handle Only VsCode.

Comment: You can google "ads drivers windows 7 oppo" to download the driver and then install it.

Comment: And this seems nothing to do with flutter. Please consider tagging only relevant keyword next time.

Comment: Have you enabled the developer mode in your device?

Comment: @hisam I've already told that "I do have enabled USB Debugging"

Comment: @ShrihanKumarPadhy no it's different.

Comment: The tapping of the version number until it says "You're now a developer"? I've done that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a bit of Googling, I found out a solution. I just needed to install a thing called **"OPPO Preloader Driver"**. Thank you everyone who participated in this thread!

Comment: You saved my day man. I was also facing the same issue since yesterday and didn't even able to identify that it's oppo specific issue

Answer (score 0):

your need Install a USB devices Drivers for (Oppo co) :

Then The command is executed in cmd to connect device with VS Code:

```
   "yourPathSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" connect 127.0.0.1:6555
```

Comment: _Where do I get the USB drivers?_

Comment: This site https://www.adbusbdriver.com/oppo-usb-drivers-for-windows/  or other site (search google)

Comment: The link was fake! After searching google, each and every link was fake.